# Where do I ask question about DNS and hosts?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Specific question that I currently have relates to the output of dig and whois utilities. While these two are executed on two different systems (remote CentOS and Debian-based desktop in residential network) the question isn't OS specific, but rather utility specific.

However, it would be nice to know where questions related to DNS, networks, domains would be on topic?

Comment: [networkengineering.se] is probably the place to try first.

Comment: @curiousdannii  In the [help section of the site](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it requires that questions asked are about networking directly under your own control. My questions are more about utilities related to networking, and not strictly related to networks I myself manage ( and in both cases for remote and local server on which I am working on right now, that's a no)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Yes, sounds like another site will be needed.

Answer (score 2):

Super User is broad enough that it would be on topic - especially when comes to that.